# debug disassembled dylib with hopper?

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb, dylib

Is there a way to connect gdb to hopper, then load a dylyb that is loaded by an app and then run the app while stepping through the dylib code? is there a way to do this?

Comment: Assuming you purchased it, why not ask the official support?

Comment: Thanks, I did a few days ago and the developer answered that this is not possible with the current version of hopper. I will mark this question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the developer and got a reply indicating that this feature (debugging a dylib), is not available in the current version.

The best way to go for now seems to be to use the available tools to find the right place to edit the code and then reassemble it.

Answer (score 2):

Today (2020) actually you can debug dylibs by opening them in a separate window before starting debugger. When you go back in the callstack window it shows the actual code in the window of dylib. You can also place breakpoints and do whatever you want in it.

For debugging to work you should remove the codesigning of the main executable.